# Why does Instagram user agent change slightly?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies, browser, instagram

I’ve been seeing some requests to my site where the user agent has Instagram in it, but the user agent changes slightly from the same IP and also the cookies then change.

The only thing that changes is that a “NW/3” string is appended on the end at the beginning and then it changes to the same header but the “NW/3” is gone.

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 191.0.0.25.122 (iPhone13,1; iOS 14_4_2; en_CA; en-CA; scale=2.88; 1080x2338; 296543649) NW/3

I thought maybe it is a malicious users because all of the cookies change right when the header changes, but I’m not 100% confident.

I tried searching Google but nothing came up, anyone seen this before and know what it is?

Comment: A short search suggests that this `NW/3` thing is a common occurrence in the Instagram app's UA strings, https://user-agents.net/applications/instagram-app What it means / its purpose is - I guess you'd have to ask Facebook.